# How to prevent opaque border inherit element's background color?

Tags: css, border

I've created a DIV with an opaque background and opaque border. The problem is that I set border's base color as black, but it still inherits a red background from the DIV.

My demo snippet:

```css
 .elem {
    height:           30px;
    width:            50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 30, 0, 0.5);
    border:           5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

The result I expected - border is opaque and black (independent). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to consider [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip):

```css
.elem {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 30, 0, 0.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```